# Problem in Setting backend data into dropdown using Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, sparql, ontology

I have a backend data and successfully set the data into dropdown but the thing is whenever click on button then it will give me the desire result but the thing is after getting the result, the drop down is like having null values in it so what can i do.

could someone suggest me whenever i click on dropdown then it will get refress or other methods are appreciable.

Thanks!

**views.py**

```html
def index(request):

    
    sparqlQueries = get_data()
    
    if(request.POST['Case_name'] and request.method =='POST'):

        name_cases = sparqlQueries.nameOfCases()
        data = {
            "cases_name":name_cases,
            'flag2':True,
            'suffix':'Cases',
            'title':'Name of Cases'
            
         }

        return render(request,'index.html',context = data) 

    if(request.method =='POST'):
        
        casename = request.POST['Case_name']
        question = request.POST['Question']
        #print(casename)
        #print(question)
        
         if(casename == 'xyz' and question == 'pqr'):
        
        judges = sparqlQueries.case2_judge_name()
        #print(judges)
        data = {
            "name":judges,
            'flag':True,
            'suffix':'judges',
            'title':'Judge of Case2'
            
         }

        return render(request,'index.html', context = data)
        
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it the wrong way:
first of all you check the request method first then check if variable exists

for `request.POST['Case_name']` if the Case_name does not exist will raise a key error internal server error, you don't need that for your project so use `request.POST.get('Case_name', optional default value)`
now for the null dropdown, it's because you didn't add the context you using in the drop down to the newly rendered template, you are not providing the full code but that's usually the reason

Comment: it's true but the thing is like i have one dropdown, one submit button and one reset button in my UI. Intially when i select the dropdown and then submit it then it's fine but after getting result or page get refressed and drop down will be empty after that. but whenever i click on reset button then page got refress and again drop down is having that backend values. so the problem is how can i fix this like after getting result the drop down will not be empty. @mohamednaser

Comment: so the thing is you have a page with some context, you post a request, the view is called process it and return a new template without the original context, you either pass it or if you want to make it global use context processors